# Openwhisk missing packages

Tags: package, openwhisk

I've installed openwhisk standalone, and successfully invoke an action.But when I run `wsk package list /whisk.system`, it show:

```
[root@localhost ~]# wsk package list /whisk.system
packages
```

According to the description in the official document, it should be displayed：

```
packages
/whisk.system/cloudant                                                 shared
/whisk.system/alarms                                                   shared
/whisk.system/watson                                                   shared
/whisk.system/websocket                                                shared
/whisk.system/weather                                                  shared
/whisk.system/system                                                   shared
/whisk.system/utils                                                    shared
/whisk.system/slack                                                    shared
/whisk.system/samples                                                  shared
/whisk.system/github                                                   shared
/whisk.system/pushnotifications                                        shared
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they are packages which need to be installed separately

see https://github.com/apache?q=openwhisk-package&type=&language=&sort= for details

Comment: Thanks! I used openwhisk-devtools to solve this problem